# ORA-01861: literal does not match format string when parsing XML date

Tags: xml, oracle

I am trying to parse this type of XML date to Oracle, but it does not work:

`select to_date('2010-09-01T00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') from dual;`

Are there any solutions to this problem?

Comment: You can try to_timestamp or to_char functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this way:

```
SELECT to_date('2010-09-01T00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS') from dual;
```

or you can try to use to_char like

```
SELECT to_char('2010-09-01T00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS') from dual;
```